# Why does the parallel command not work with backslashes when taking input from file?

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, scripting

Consider the following file saved as `commands.txt`

```
ls \
&& pwd

ls \
&& pwd
```

Now,

```
bash commands.txt
```

works as expected to give

```
LICENSE
/home/username/utilities
LICENSE
/home/username/utilities
```

but

```
parallel < commands.txt
```

gives the error

```
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `&&'
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: `&& pwd'
ls: cannot access '\': No such file or directory
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `&&'
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: `&& pwd
```

Why do multiple lines with the same command separated by `\` not seem to work with `parralel` as such?

Answer (score 1):

> Why do multiple lines with the same command separated by \ not seem to work with parralel as such?

Because `parallel` does not parse `\` and executes a separate shell for each line.

Comment: so does that mean there is no way to cleanly separate long commands for parallel if you keep them in a file?

Comment: Also is this there in the manual (or how do you find this out?)

Comment: `so does that mean there is no way to cleanly separate long commands for parallel if you keep them in a file?` There is always "a way". You can patch parallel with the behavior that you want to have or preprocess the file. `is this there in the manual` all resources are avaliable from gnu site https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/ `how do you find this out?` I interpreted the results you showed with the description of parallel: "For each line of input GNU parallel will execute command with the line as arguments".

Comment: You could use the command.txt as a shell script and execute that with parallel instead of using it as input for parallel.

Comment: @Phillip-ZyanKLee-Stockmann no idea how that is done

Answer (score 0):

If your input has `\n\n` after each group (and only there), you can do:

```
cat commands.txt | parallel -d '\n\n'
```